# Android BaseFragment class with multiple different fragment types

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created a base fragment class that handles setting the toolbar title, registering for when the fragment is attached, setting the menu icons and a few other things. My issue is that I've decided to use the PreferencesFragmentCompat for my settings fragment and I cant extend both my BaseFragment and androids PreferencesFragmentCompat. Using an interface here wouldn't help because my BaseFragment has a lot of functionality, and I don't want to duplicate it into each of my fragment classes. Normally to extend two classes, you just do it in two seperate files but because both already extend off Androids Fragment class, I dont see how this is possible. Is there a better way of doing this?

[image]

BaseFragment:

```
 public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    protected View rootView;
    protected AppSettings settings;
    protected LayoutInflater inflater;

    public static void startFragment(Activity activity, BaseFragment newFragment) {
        FragmentManager fragManager = ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
        BaseFragment currentFragment = (BaseFragment) fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        // Start the transactions
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);

        // If there is already a fragment then we want it on the backstack
        if (currentFragment != null) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        // Show it
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    private void lockMode(boolean start) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            if (start) {
                getActivity().startLockTask();
            } else {
                getActivity().stopLockTask();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get a reference to the app settings
        settings = AppSettings.getInstance(getActivity());

        // Don't want keyboard to stay open between fragments
        hideKeyboard();

        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            if (toolbarElevation()) {
                actionBar.setElevation(4 * getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            } else {
                actionBar.setElevation(0);
            }
        }

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Set the title up
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

        // Enable the home button in the action bar
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        // Change the home button icon for menu or back
        if (showUpNavigation()) {
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_navigation_back_white);
        } else {
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_white);
        }

        if (isAppInLockTaskMode() == true && pinnedMode() == false) {
            lockMode(false);
        }

        setDrawerMenu();
    }

    public boolean getAuthRequired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isBackAllowed() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean toolbarElevation() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return "ISOPED";
    }

    public boolean pinnedMode() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean showUpNavigation() {
        return false;
    }

    public void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        // check if no view has focus:
        View v = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (v == null) {
            return;
        }

        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public void setDrawerMenu() {
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_navigation);
        Integer menuID = null;
        Integer currentMenuId = null;

        if (settings.isType(AppSettings.TYPES.PERSONAL)) {
            menuID = R.menu.drawer_personal;
        } else if (settings.isType(AppSettings.TYPES.PROFESSIONAL)) {
            if (getAuthRequired() == true) {
                menuID = R.menu.drawer_professional_locked;
            } else {
                menuID = R.menu.drawer_professional_unlocked;
            }
        }

        if (menuID != null) {
            if (navigationView.getTag() != null) {
                currentMenuId = (Integer) navigationView.getTag();
            }

            if (currentMenuId == null || navigationView.getMenu().size() == 0 || currentMenuId != menuID) {
                navigationView.getMenu().clear();
                navigationView.inflateMenu(menuID);
                navigationView.setTag(Integer.valueOf(menuID));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();

        if (settings.isType(AppSettings.TYPES.PROFESSIONAL) && pinnedMode() && false == isAppInLockTaskMode()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.pin_menu, menu);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (showUpNavigation()) {
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_pin:
                if (isAppInLockTaskMode()) {
                    PinDialog dialog = new PinDialog((AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), new NavigationCallback((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()) {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            lockMode(false);
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                } else {
                    lockMode(true);
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private boolean isAppInLockTaskMode() {
        ActivityManager activityManager;

        activityManager = (ActivityManager)
                getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // For SDK version 23 and above.
            return activityManager.getLockTaskModeState()
                    != ActivityManager.LOCK_TASK_MODE_NONE;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // When SDK version >= 21. This API is deprecated in 23.
            return activityManager.isInLockTaskMode();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice example, where you should apply [Joshua Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch)'s *[**"Favor composition over inheritance"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)* idiom.

You can delegate all the logic that you have applied to `BaseFragment` to some class `FragmentHelper`:

```
public class FragmentHelper {

    private final Fragment fragment;

    public FragmentHelper(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public void create(Bundle bundle) {
      // `BaseFragment`'s code goes here
    }

    public void resume() {
      // `BaseFragment`'s code goes here
    }

    ...
}
```

Now in your BaseFragment:

```
public class BaseFragment {

    private FragmentHelper fragmentHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        fragmentHelper = new FragmentHelper(this);
        fragmentHelper.create(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        fragmentHelper.resume();
    }
}
```

And the same this should be applied to the class that is extending `PreferenceFragment`.

Thus, you'd evade from code duplication.

Reference:

- Joshua Bloch - Effective Java 2nd edition, Item 16.